# ImageButton is visible only after resize - Libgdx

Tags: resize, libgdx, visibility, imagebutton, scene2d

I have a class called "HudBarView" which takes care of the drawing of the HUD Bar at the top of the screen(Pause button, score, etc).

This class extends the Group class(scene2d).

Another class I have is "HUDManager" which takes care of all the HUD work in the game, including HUD Bar.

Now, currently I have only a pause button in my HUD Bar but the problem is - it is visible only after I resize the screen. Very weird problem.

Here is my HudBarView class:

```
package views.hud.views;

import views.renderers.HUDManager;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;

import engine.helpers.AssetsManager;
import engine.helpers.Values;

public class HUDBarView extends Group{

    private ImageButton pause;
    private HUDManager hud_manager;
    private Skin skin;
    public HUDBarView(HUDManager hud_manager) {
        this.hud_manager = hud_manager;
        initiate();
    }
    private void initiate() {
        skin = new Skin(AssetsManager.getAsset(Values.BUTTONS_PACK, TextureAtlas.class));
        pause = new ImageButton(skin.getDrawable("pause"));
        pause.setSize(Values.Pause_Width, Values.Pause_Height);
        pause.setPosition(Values.SCREEN_WIDTH - pause.getWidth(), Values.SCREEN_HEIGHT- pause.getHeight());
        addActor(pause);
    }
}
```

Here is my HUDManager class:

```
package views.renderers;

import views.hud.ParticleEffectsActor;
import views.hud.views.HUDBarView;
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenManager;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;

import engine.helpers.AssetsManager;
import engine.helpers.UIHelper;
import engine.helpers.Values;

public class HUDManager extends Group {

    private Stage stage;
    private Skin skin;
    private Image text;
    private HUDBarView hudView;

    public HUDManager(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
        initiate();
        addActor(hudView);
        addActor(particles);
    }

    public void initiate() {
        skin = AssetsManager.getAsset(Values.GAME_SKIN_PACK, Skin.class);
        hudView = new HUDBarView(this);
        particles = new ParticleEffectsActor();
    }

    public Stage getStage() {
        return stage;
    }
}
```

Here are some photos that will help you understand the problem a little bit better:
Before the screen is resized(it doesn't matter how much the screen is resized):
http://i.gyazo.com/5cc675bde2fcbba7492bba69d4a419c6.png
After the screen is resized:
http://i.gyazo.com/d6814f3e15b903d59dab74b83e95292c.png

P.S Here is my render method inside the Game Screen class(I omitted all the irrelevant parts):

```
public void render(float delta) {
        switch(state) {
        case RUN:
            // if The asset manager is done loading
            if(AssetsManager.update() && !doneLoading) {
                 doneLoading = true;
                 hudManager = new HUDManager(stage);
                 stage.addActor(hudManager);
                 renderer = new GameRenderer(world, camera, batch);
                 loadingRenderer.dispose();
            } else if(doneLoading) {
                renderer.render(delta);
                stage.draw();
                stage.act(delta);
                world.update(delta);
                manager.update(delta);
            }
            // Display loading information
            else
                loadingRenderer.render(AssetsManager.getProgress()*100);
        case PAUSE:
            break;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: After playing a little bit with the code I found out that if I pause and then resume the game it causes the ImageButton to appear on the screen.

Comment: When do you call `hudManager.initiate()`? Looks like that's required to get the button added to your stage, but you're not calling it at any point after your assets are loaded. So I'm guessing you're calling it in `resize` which is why that fixes the issue. BTW, you might want the `initiate` method to clear the stage at first to avoid adding duplicate items if it gets called more than once.

Comment: I'm calling it inside the hud manager class, in its constructor, as you can see in the code. I excidently defined public instead of private. This problem doesn't make any sense because I'm not even messing with the resize method in the game screen class. It is like the stage is refreshed after the screen is resized.

Comment: Assuming you are properly updating the stage's viewport in the `resize` method, then, yes, it is refreshing the stage on `resize`.  But a quick scan of your code shows that your hud manager is instantiated before loading is complete, so maybe it doesn't have the parameters necessary to size the widgets at the time you first build your hud, and later when you resize, it's after loading is complete.

Comment: You are wrong. My hud manager is instantiated after the assests are loaded. That's why I put the if statement inside the render method. Regarding the resize method, what do you mean update the stage's viewport in the resize method?

Comment: Oops, I see now! You're supposed to call `stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);` in the `resize` method of your game or screen so the stage knows how to properly size what's in it.

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work. I have tried what you said and it didn't solve the problem. Thanks for your help though!